# React Hooks Question: opening a modular modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing a **React.js** application based on **Material UI** for a school project. My project is based on the [React + Material UI + Firebase](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase) example found in the Material UI docs. Currently, I am trying to employ `React Hooks` so I can avoid using Redux (and get better at something that'll be developing in the future).
In the app component, they have an **openDialog** function, which operates as a way to open a modal based on the dialogId.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {
  signUpDialog: {
    open: false
  },

  signInDialog: {
    open: false
  },

  settingsDialog: {
    open: false
  },

  signOutDialog: {
    open: false
  }
};
}

// CURRENT, NON-HOOKS WAY
openDialog = (dialogId, callback) => {
   const dialog = this.state[dialogId];

   if (!dialog || dialog.open === undefined || null) {
     return;
   }
   dialog.open = true;

   this.setState({ dialog }, callback);
 };
```

They then have a Navbar than call this function with the corresponding dialog (e.g. `onSignUpClick={() => this.openDialog('signUpDialog')}`)
I am currently trying to move this over using hooks

Can someone please teach/help me convert this modular function for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
const [dialog, setDialog] = useState({
  isOpensignUp: false,
  isOpenSignIn: false,
  isOpenSignOut: false,
  isOpenSetting: false
});

const handleDialog =  e  => {
  setDialog({...dialog,[e.target.name]:true});
}

<button name= "isOpensignUp" onClick={handleDialog} />
<Dialog open={dialog.isOpensignUp}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'

function App({ callback }) {

  // if we just mind about the active dialog,
  // we don't need to save the state of the others
  const [dialog, setDialog] = React.useState(null)

  // here useEffect is called every time, dialog changed,
  // we also need to put `callback` in the array otherwise
  // React throw a warning.

  // React.useEffect act like `ComponentDidMount`, so we better
  // check dialog is not empty otherwise it will call our callback
  // straight away AFTER the render and that's not what we want
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (dialog) callback()
  }, [dialog, callback])

  // You said we were in a navBar so i can assume you can do 
  // something like this
  return (
    <div>
      {['signUp', 'signInDialog', 'settingsDialog', 'signOutDialog'].map(
        elem => (
          <div key={elem} onClick={() => setDialog({ [elem]: true })}>
            {elem}
          </div>
        ),
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```